# Gson deserializing an Array of Objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an object

```
public class Point{
    int x, y;

    Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String ret = "[";
        ret += Integer.toString(x);
        ret += ", ";
        ret += Integer.toString(y);
        ret += "]";
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I have been able to deserialize this object with Gson like so:

```
class PointDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Point>{
    @Override
    public Point deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
    JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int[] tmp = gson.fromJson(json, int[].class);
        int a = tmp[0];
        int b = tmp[1];
        return new Point(a,b);
    }               
}
```

Now, I use the following at last to make it work. Note that type and str are strings.

```
Class myClass = Class.forName(type);
Class myClassDeserializer = Class.forName(type + "Deserializer");
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(myClass, myClassDeserializer.newInstance()).create();
Object ret = gson.fromJson(str, myClass);
```

Now here is the main problem. I want to do this for classes `Point[]`, `Point[][]` and so on also.

Will I have to write a deserializer for every dimension of Point or is there a better way to do it?

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

First off, you're really introducing a bit of un-needed overhead in your deserializer. There's no need to create the native Java array; you already have a JSON array:

```
class PointDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Point> {

    @Override
    public Point deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray(); 
        return new Point(array.get(0).getAsInt(), array.get(1).getAsInt());

    }
}
```

Once you register that with Gson via `registerTypeAdapter`, arrays of that type "just work":

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String json = "[ [1,2], [3,4] ]";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Point.class, 
                    new MyPointDeserializer()).create();

    Point[] mpa = gson.fromJson(json, Point[].class);        
    System.out.println(mpa[1].x);
}
```

Output:

> 3

The trouble you'll run into is that you're needing to get the `Class` dynamically and you want an array type. You can achieve this for array types by prepending `[L` to the fully qualified class name:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("[L" + "my.package.Point");
```

`myClass` now holds `Point[].class`

This kinda gets rather ugly in a hurry when you start talking about multiple dimensions. It works ... you can use additional `[` to represent the dimensions ... but then you still need to get it back as an `Object` and cast, etc.

Honestly, the better way to do it is via a `List` type with a `TypeToken`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String json = "[ [[1,2]], [[3,4]] ]";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Point.class, new MyPointDeserializer()).create();

    Point[][] mpa = gson.fromJson(json, Point[][].class);

    System.out.println(mpa[1][0].x);

    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>>(){}.getType();

    List<List<Point>> list = gson.fromJson(json, listType);

    System.out.println(list.get(1).get(0).x);

}
```

Output:

> 3
> 3

Answer (score 2):

This is how to deserialize array of objects:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<YourObject>>(){}.getType();
List<YourObject> yourObjectsList= gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

GSon has its own [`ArrayTypeAdapter`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ArrayTypeAdapter.java) that is used internally. I suppose it will be used automatically when you try to deserialise an array, since the same is done for `List` and other collections.

Since its internal to GSon, you should usually not have to perform any actions to enable or use it.

Comment: Can you please give some details on how to do it?